# Splash screen. ( Angular2)

Tags: angular, typescript, splash-screen

I am using webpack + angular2 starter kit.

```
  <app>
    Loading...
  </app>
```

But when I want to use Splash component instead of "Loading"

```
  <app>
    <splash></splash>
  </app>
```

I have not any splash screen.

Can somebody helps me?

Comment: any console error? does `splash` component has been included in `AppModule`'s `declarations`? We need more code to help accurately

Comment: Can you add more information on how your application is structured?
It is going to be very hard to troubleshoot with so little information.
Maybe set up a codepen/fiddle etc.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly I don't think what you're attempting will work. If that slash element is an angular2 component it won't exist until your bundle loads, at which point anything inside of <app> is replaced with the actual app. You can create the splash in standard HTML / inlined CSS if you want it to display before app load.

Comment: How I can load splash component first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My implementation:

```
<app>

  <div class="splashPage">
    <div class="splashHeader">
      Please wait, we are preparing unTill WM for you. <br>
      Just few moments left.
    </div>
    <div class="spinner">
      <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/Logo_112x112.png" />
      <img id="spinnerCircle" src="../assets/img/spinner.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="splashFooter">
      <div class="mobileLabel">Available on</div>
        <div class="mobileApps">
                <img src="../assets/img/Apple.png"/>
                <img src="../assets/img/Android.png"/>
                <img src="../assets/img/Windows.png"/>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div></app>
```

Splash screen is visible before app started work.

Also added css in head:

```
<link href="assets/css/splash.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```